# Raspberry Pi ffmpeg live camera stream over 4g

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, raspberry-pi, 4g

I'm planning on connecting a camera to a Raspberry Pi and streaming video over 4G internet to control a quad copter. I will be using ffmpeg to stream the video, so far it looks like you need to use ffserver to do this. The problem is most 4G providers (I use AT&T) block all ports from hosting. Would something like FreedomPop (http://www.freedompop.com) work? Can I stream with ffmpeg as the client? What kind of latency can I expect?

Answer (score 0):

Use rtmp or rtsp uni cast protocols for the lowest latency.

You could do ffmpeg server but may find something like wowza on amazon easier.

At best your latency will be a few seconds.

Comment: rtmp & rtsp both require that the person broadcasting be the server which is what I am trying to avoid. Or find a 4G ISP that allows you to host server (forward ports)

Answer (score 0):

I have used freedom pop with my raspberry pi and a ddns address to connect to without problems.